# onNotificationOpened method not getting called in react native firebase

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

i am using react-native-firebase for notification in my react native project and i am trying to call onNotificationOpened and getInitialNotification from componentDidMount method but these two methods not getting called, any suggestion will be appreciated

```js
this.removeNotificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
    console.log('onNotificationOpened AppJS :', notificationOpen)
    const { action, notification } = notificationOpen
    let item = JSON.parse(notification.data.body)
    console.log('onNotificationOpened AppJS : body ', item)

    console.log('onNotificationOpened AppJS : action ', action)

})

firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification()
    .then((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
        if (notificationOpen) {
            console.log('getInitialNotification AppJS : Shoeb ########: ')
            // App was opened by a notification
            // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
            const { action, notification } = notificationOpen
            let item = JSON.parse(notification.data.body)
            console.log('getInitialNotification AppJS : item ', item)
            console.log('getInitialNotification AppJS : action ', action)

        }
    })
```

Comment: Did you receive the notification in either "onNotification" or "onMessage" function?

Comment: yes onNotification i received notification but when app is in background and i clicked on notification curtain nothing happens

Comment: Where did you place this code "this.removeNotificationOpenedListener = "?

Comment: in componentDidMount of App.js file

Comment: If your app is in the foreground or background, you should get that callback triggered when a notification is clicked/tapped/opened. If still, that didn't happen check for logs in debugger or check the Android Studio Logcat. You will be able to debug further